# Is there a way to load mustache partials automatically in express + consolidate

Tags: express, partials, mustache

I'm using express + consolidate + mustache as template engine and I was wondering if there's a way to teach express to automatically load partials with matching filenames which I have not explicitly defined.

**Example:**

```
head.html:
---
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title></title></head><body>


index.html:
---
{{> head}}
{{content}}
{{> foot}}


foot.html:
---
</body></html>


app.js:
---
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html', {
        partials: {
            head: 'head', 
            foot: 'foot'
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see, the `head` and `foot` partials are named exactly as their according filenames (minus `.html`). Doing it that way works fine but I'm looking for an easy way to let express/mustache load partials automatically if there's a matching filename; without the need to specify my default partials in each and every function again. `{{> example}}` -> looks if `views/example.html` exists and loads it if `example` is not defined in the partials object).

Is that possible?

Or is there at least an easy way to define default partials globally?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with consolidate yet. We had the exact same problem (be able to call partials by their names without having to tell hogan/consolidate to load them everytime) and couldn't find a good module so we made our own, which we have been using in production for a few weeks: [h4e](https://github.com/tldrio/h4e)  ("Hogan for Express"). With it all partials are loaded automatically and you can also use layouts if you want to.

I think it should answer your need.
Louis